# загрузка картинок png и svg через Glide

Tags: android, glide

В своем приложении через RecyclerView я вывожу результаты матчей, и каждая строка результата дополняется названием команды и логотипом клуба. В основном, преобладают изображения формата svg и строки с двумя такими форматами изображений отображаются корректно. Проблемы возникаю, если в строке у меня подгружаются эмблемы с разными форматами (png и svg). То есть если первым подгружается png, то следующее изображение формата svg не выводится, и наоборот (то есть будет отображаться корректно только первый логотип).
Пробовал разделить загрузку по разным библиотекам (тоесть для png применить picasso, а для svg оставить glide - не сработало)

Подозреваю, что проблема в этом блоке кода (метод связывающий данные в классе ViewHolder)

```
public void bindEvents(Event event) {
            mLeagueCaption.setText("");
            mHomeTeamName.setText(event.getHomeTeamName());
            mAwayTeamName.setText(event.getAwayTeamName());

            homeTeamUrl = event.getHomeTeamUrl();
            Uri uri = Uri.parse( homeTeamUrl);
            if (homeTeamUrl.endsWith(".svg")) {
                showIfSVG(uri, mHomeTeamImage);
            }
            else{
                showIfPNG(uri, mHomeTeamImage);
            }

            awayTeamUrl = event.getAwayTeamUrl();
            uri = Uri.parse( awayTeamUrl);
            if (homeTeamUrl.endsWith(".svg")) {
                showIfSVG(uri, mAwayTeamImage);
            }
            else{
                showIfPNG(uri, mAwayTeamImage);
            }

            if (event.getResult().getGoalsHomeTeam() == -1
                    || event.getResult().getGoalsAwayTeam() == -1) {
                mScore.setText(timeOfMatch);
            } else {
                mScore.setText(event.getResult().getGoalsHomeTeam() + " : " + event.getResult().getGoalsAwayTeam());
            }
            mDate.setText(dateOfMatch);
            matchId = event.getMatchId();
        }

        private void showIfSVG(Uri uri, ImageView view){
            mRequestBuilder
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
                    .load(uri)
                    .into(view);
        }

        private void showIfPNG(Uri uri, ImageView view){
            Glide
                    .with(mActivity)
                    .load(uri)
                    .into(view);
        }
```

Comment: Попробуйте `Glide.clear(view);` вызвать перед собственно отображением картинки.

Comment: к сожалению, не помогло